# Broken Package links for ksoap2 .jars?

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm currently trying to build a little application on android that is using a webspace but the problem ist that if I want to download a ksoap2 package (e.g. ksoap2 with all dependencies 2.5.2 from [here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/#svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.5.2)) the filesize is 21.6KB after downloading. But the table says 141KB.

This is resulting into printing out errors when I try to import it as an external library (not compatible to Dalvik) which is un derstandable because the archive is corrupt/broke.

Can someone give me a link where can download a proper .jar-archive?

(2nd question: how do I use the javadocs? do I have to set them into the path if I click on the external libraries dialog->ksoap2...->javadoc ?)

thanks in advance

Comment: I contactes the support and they updated the wikipage so that it is stated on how to obtain the .jar files

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=40
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded the latest Ksoap2 Version. It can only be downloaded 10 times.
http://rapidshare.com/files/434471358/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar

But I see, you've alredy fixed it. ;)